# Создать ключи и свойства обьекта на основе массива

Tags: javascript

Как написать функция который будет создавать объект на основе массива.

Дан массив:

```
const entry = ["index","footer","header"];
```

На основе этого массива надо создать объект с таким же ключом и значением.На выходе надо получить следующее:

```
obj = {
  index:"index",
  footer:"footer",
  header:"header"
}
```

Я попытался написать так:

```js
const entry = ["index","footer","header"];

const obj = {};

entry.forEach((o,i) => {
  obj[i] = {name:o};
});
console.log(obj);
```

Но этот код создает несколько  объектов с одним и тем же ключом `name` если заменить внутри `forEach` `name` на `o` будет ошибка:

```
{
  "0": {
    "name": "index"
  },
  "1": {
    "name": "footer"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "header"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то как-то так

```js
const entry = ["index", "footer", "header"];

const obj = {};

entry.forEach((o, i) => {
  obj[o] = o;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Прочтите внимательно вопрос пожалуйста.И что должно получится на выходе.

Comment: @Demon__, а сейчас так?

Comment: Отлично спасибо.

Comment: xD 2 одинаковых ответа на такой вопрос...да Вы издеваетесь !

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц не понял.Почему вы удалили свой ответ.

Comment: @Demon__ ну я дал точ в точ ответ..только немного раньше. И участник с 3к репы его копипастит (я уверен что было не так )))))

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц зря вы удалили добавьте его еще раз.Я дал плюс для поддержания вашего ответа.Этот вопрос уникален и такого нету в SORU.Я принял ответ tCode так как он написал его первым.Не обижайтесь пожалуйста.

Comment: @Demon__ я на сайте сижу не ради балов, и я не в коем случает не обиделся...просто я думаю что не стоит писать одинаковые ответы. p s этот участник изначально дал раньше ответ (но ответ был не верным). Поэтому я написал свой. После того как этот участник изменил свой ответ, то он был написан так же как и мой. Не вижу смысла от моего.